# Zero Offsetting P1 pedals using just Rouvy android mobile app

Tags: power

I don't have a bike computer, rather I use my old cellphone for that matter. Does anybody know how to do a zero offset of P1S pedals using Rouvy app? Apparently, there should be an option when you pair your sensor, but on my app I don't have one. Please see the attachment and thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I was received from Rouvy help desk:

"The problem is that this feature is `not available on Android`. But, you can use any desktop app and just Zero offset your pedals and then use your phone for a ride."